# Solana REST API - getting metadata

Tags: rest, solana

I am new in this world and don't have experience. is there API for solana? if yes could you please a tutorial or give tipp . For example can i getting the matadata?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solana has a JSON RPC API that you can use to grab data on the chain:

https://docs.solana.com/developing/clients/jsonrpc-api